# Assigning function return value DIRECTLY in template - Smarty 2

Tags: php, smarty

I have global function defined in php:

```
function tabIsProtected($tabNr)
{
    ...
    return true;
}
```

Now this **works** in Smarty:

```
    {if tabIsProtected($tabnr)}
        {assign var="tabProtected" value=true}
    {else}
        {assign var="tabProtected" value=false}
    {/if}
```

And this **is not**:

```
{assign var="tabProtected" value=tabIsProtected($tabnr)}
```

When I print $tabProtected variable I get string "tabIsProtected(9)" (for $tabnr = 9) and function tabIsProtected isn't even called!

**Is there any way to assign function return value directly in template using Smarty 2?**

IMPORTANT: I don't want $smarty->assign(...) in php or Smarty3 solutions. Just one liner directly in template.